# Changing the order of html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that displays and hides content. The only thing I cant figure out is how to always have the most recently displayed element always display on top of the others as they fade out. If you click the buttons left to right you can see how I want it to work. But right to left doesn't work the same way due to the order of the html. I thought about using index but I couldn't think of how to get it to work. Help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
       
    var current_sec = $(this).data("section"); 
    $(".sections").not(this).removeClass("show"); 
    $('.click').not(this).removeClass("clicked");
    
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){  
      $("#" + current_sec).removeClass("show"); 
      $(this).removeClass("clicked"); 
    } else{  
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      $("#" + current_sec).addClass("show"); 
      $(".show_all").removeClass("all_open"); 
      $(".show_all").html("Our skills");
    }
  });
  
  $(".show_all").click(function(){
    if($(".show_all").hasClass("all_open")){ 
      $(".sections").removeClass("show"); 
      $(".show_all").removeClass("all_open"); 
      $(".click").removeClass("clicked");
      $(".show_all").html("Our skills");
    } else{
      $(".sections").addClass("show");
      $(".show_all").addClass("all_open");
      $(".show_all").html("close skills"); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.click{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#two{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three{
  background-color: red;
}

#four{
  background-color: orange;
}

.sections{
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.show{
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#section_1{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#section_2{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section_3{
  background-color: red;
}

#section_4{
  background-color: orange;
}

.show_all{
  font-weight: 800;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="click" data-section="section_1"></div>
<div id="two" class="click" data-section="section_2"></div>
<div id="three" class="click" data-section="section_3"></div>
<div id="four" class="click" data-section="section_4"></div>

<div class="sections" id="section_1">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque. <a href="#" class="show_all">our skills</a></p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_2">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque. <a href="#" class="show_all">our skills</a></p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_3">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque. <a href="#" class="show_all">our skills</a></p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_4">
   <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque. <a href="#" class="show_all">our skills</a></p>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this but you have an effect new problem.

```
      ...
      $(this).removeClass("clicked"); 
   } else{  
      // move the div on top, after last .click
      $('.click:last').after( $("#" + current_sec));

      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Store a z-index in a variable. Increment it on each click, and assign it to the shown section. This way, the latest shown section will always be on top.

```
var zIndex = 1;

$(".click").click(function(){
    // ...
    $("#" + current_sec).addClass("show").css("z-index", ++zIndex)
}
```

Comment: Of course, got a silent downvote. Thank you, silent downvoter.